Order of magnitude for entropy change of solvation of H2O2
I have found that entropy change for the solvation of hydrogen peroxide $(\ce{H2O2})$ is negligible, in the order of $10^{-7}$ from the standardized mean difference (SMD) calculation, but from the experimental data I found from Webbook, entropy change is in the order of $10^{-4}$. Does that mean I did the SMD calculation wrong or is it because SMD cannot accurately predict solute-solvent interactions?
Below are the energy terms for gas and aqueous phase calculation of $\ce{H2O2}$ by Gaussian PBE/cc-pVDZ:
From gas phase calculation:

Zero-point correction $= \pu{0.024663 Hartree/Particle}$
Thermal correction to Energy $= 0.027571$
Thermal correction to Enthalpy $= 0.028516$
Thermal correction to Gibbs Free Energy $= 0.003132$
Sum of electronic and zero-point Energies $= -151.370544$
Sum of electronic and thermal Energies $= -151.367635$
Sum of electronic and thermal Enthalpies $= -151.366691$
Sum of electronic and thermal Free Energies $= -151.392075$

From aqueous phase calculation:

Zero-point correction $= \pu{0.024578 Hartree/Particle}$
Thermal correction to Energy $= 0.027484$
Thermal correction to Enthalpy $= 0.028429$
Thermal correction to Gibbs Free Energy $= 0.003048$
Sum of electronic and zero-point Energies $= -151.382628$
Sum of electronic and thermal Energies $= -151.379721$
Sum of electronic and thermal Enthalpies $= -151.378777$
Sum of electronic and thermal Free Energies $= -151.404158$

